# How can I translate a string with special character into another string where these are escaped

Tags: java, string, unicode, char, escaping

I'm looking for a function in the Java SE library or some common ones (e.g. apache-commons) that already provides an implementation of the following:

Say, I have a string with non-printable and special character such as tabs... I would like to be able to obtain a representation of such a string that tells the reader the actual composition of the string:

So for example:

```
String input = "hello\tworld!!!";
System.out.println(input); \\ output looks like: hello    world!!!
String output = printable(input);
System.out.println(output); \\ output looks like: hello\tworld!!!
                           \\ or
                           \\ output looks like: hello<TAB>world!!!
                           \\ or
                           \\ output looks like: hello\011world!!!
```

The exact form is not important but it should be good enough so that it shows the 
content of the string in unambiguous manner and in a way that can be understood by a programmer.

I can code my own solution but I wonder whether there is something already in existence.

Comment: Does indeed seem to be a duplicate.  I am surprised, however, that only one of the proposed solutions actually returns the same string that was passed in if no escaping was necessary.  And that solution didn't even solve the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils`. It's available in Apache commons-lang3.

```
String input = "hello\tworld!!!";
System.out.println(input); //output looks like: hello    world!!!
String output = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(input);
System.out.println(output);//output looks like: hello\tworld!!!
```